# how to download using wget in binary mode - linux

Tags: linux, wget

I need to download `*.tar.gz` file from server but when I do that, I get an error

```
ERROR: The ./files.tic seems to be corrupted.
```

I think it is because it has been downloaded in ASCII mode, and I need to download in binary mode.
How to run `wget` in binary mode? Or any other command to get binary file.

This file is from `http`, not `ftp`.

Comment: HTTP doesn't have the special TEXT mode that FTP does, so it may well be that the source file is corrupt, or an intermediary cache has cached a corrupt version.

Comment: `files.tic`? Where did that come from?

Comment: From archive. File I need to download is [here](http://download.sybase.com/eval/unix/linux_x86_GA_sa1001.3415_l10n.tar.gz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the MIME type for the file does not change its contents. So you should be already getting the right representation of it. HTTP protocol does not have text/binary types for data. Data is data :)

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Response_message for further info.

Comment: They should have a checksum available on their webpage. A good practice is also signing a file with PGP key to check if the file is not corrupted or modified by someone else. Example: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VerifyIsoHowto and the directory listing: http://mirror.eftel.com/ubuntu-dvd/precise/release/

Comment: OK, I just downloaded the file. Looks it is not corrupted for me. `tar -xzvf linux_x86_GA_sa1001.3415_l10n.tar.gz` worked OK. The `md5sum linux_x86_GA_sa1001.3415_l10n.tar.gz` shows: 221bf2faa76101b138a1a26628b75f55. I have used ... firefox :)

Comment: can you run `./setup` without any errors? I'm get `The  "/root/ga1101/files.tic" seems to be corrupted.` I'm using console, I'm doing this on VPS.